# Multiple JDBC files on Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc, mariadb

In my project, I should use both SQLiteDB and MariaDB.

So, I imported jdbc driver files(*.jar) in the eclipse project.

[image]

But I got an error like this:

Code:

```
public DBHelper() {
    try {
        driver = (Driver) Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC").newInstance();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    makeConnections();
}

public synchronized boolean makeConnections() {
    try {
        switch (ConnectionManager.getDatabaseType()) {
        case SQLITE:
            if (conn == null || conn.isClosed()) {
                SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
                config.setJournalMode(JournalMode.WAL);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:data.sqlite", config.toProperties());
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            }
            break;
        case MARIADB:
            if (conn == null || conn.isClosed()) {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://data.mariadb");
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            }
            break;
        }

        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connection URL url jdbc:sqlite:data.sqlite
at org.mariadb.jdbc.JDBCUrl.parse(JDBCUrl.java:144)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:95)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at database.DBHelper.makeConnections(DBHelper.java:96)
at database.DBHelper.<init>(DBHelper.java:60)
at database.DBHelper.getSingleton(DBHelper.java:28)
```

I clearly registered the jdbc driver with the name "**org.sqlite.JDBC**". But I don't know why the log message contains "at org.**mariadb**.jdbc.Driver.connect(...)".

After the MariaDB jdbc file(*.jar) is removed, the program is successfully executed.

Comment: Post full code of your DBHelper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself. JDBC 4.0 uses the `ServiceLoader` mechanism besides manually loading classes. So, `Class.ForName` is no longer used to explicitly load a JDBC Driver. So I removed the following lines from my code:

```
try {
    driver = (Driver) Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC").newInstance();
    DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

By just removing the above lines, the program automatically found the appropriate JDBC driver and worked well.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a problem with the mariadb 1.2.0 jdbc driver and occurs in combination with every other jdbc driver. See

https://mariadb.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/CONJ-167

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code:

```
driver = (Driver) Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC").newInstance();
DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
```

and replace with

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")
```

That's all you have to do to load the appropriate driver. Reason for this is when the driver class is loaded by the class loaded it will automatically register itself with the DriverManager. You should also do this for the MariaDB driver class.